# Macbook air 13 screen off randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Air 13" and right from the start I kept having this weird issue:

**Sometimes while I'm working on it, the screen randomly shuts off** (or goes to sleep). The computer is still active and everything is still running, so If I hit a key it goes back on normally. It happens even if my power cord is plugged in.

I have turned off  `put screen to sleep`.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?
Listed by owning process:
pid 448(com.apple.preferences.softwareu): [0x000000ed000182f9] 00:47:33 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.install"
Timeout will fire in 11547 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
pid 280(softwareupdated): [0x00000a1b00018d73] 00:08:16 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.SoftwareUpdateMacController.msu.PrepareUpdate"
pid 139(WindowServer): [0x000005fc0009885b] 00:00:07 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:10000033f name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"
Timeout will fire in 172 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
pid 492(SoftwareUpdateNotificationManag): [0x000000ed000182f8] 00:47:33 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.RestartCountdownOperationIdleSleep"
Timeout will fire in 747 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler

Comment: Welcome on AskDifferent. Please have a look at the Tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. Further we would need more details about the machine and what you have tried so far. What macOS version are you running? Have you tried restarting, resetting SMC, NVRAM/PRAM, single user/safe-mode? Also, are you sure it is not the ambient light sensor *dimming* the display or does it actually *turn off*? Further, does it happen with every app under every workload or can you narrow it down to a specific use case?

Comment: The next time this happens, go to *Terminal*, run the following command, and copy the log messages from the last minute or so: `$ pmset -g log` Then add them to your question so we can take a look.

Comment: Currently i am using macbook air 13, OS big sur 11.2.Yes i have tried restarting, resetting SMC , PRAM and safe mode . It happens any app i use even if there is no workload.@ X_841

Comment: Timeout will fire in 172 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 100(mds) Timeout will fire in 172 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 100(mds): [0x00000015000b8023] 00:02:03 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"  : [0x00000015000b8023] 00:02:03 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"

Comment: @JaneAlam Since you’re on Big Sur the command will be different: **The next time this happens**, after rebooting go to *Terminal* and run  `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 30m`